# How to cancel the submit of a button with jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, input

When I'm using jQuery UI input feature, when button has been clicked, it submit/refresh the entire webpage.  How can I stop/cancel the entire web to reload?

```
<input style='width:65px;' type='button' class='ui-button ui-button-text-only ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all Bags' id='Buy' name='".$idn."' value='Buy Bags'>
```

Was it something like:

```
$('.Bags').click(function(){
    var $a = $(this).val();
    var $b = $(this).attr('id');
    var $c = $(this).attr('name');
    /* input/button is the issue, how do i stop the form from refreshing? */
});
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

After learning a few things here/there, found another easy way to do this, tho some may disagree, but it works so far:

```
<input style='width:65px;' type='button' class='Bags' id='Buy' name='".$idn."' value='Buy Bags' onclick='return false;'>
```

By adding "**onClick='return false;'**" will stop the form from refreshing/reloading.

Comment: How to do *what* in jQuery? Your question is unclear.

Comment: ..might not be such a terrible idea to state your goal. You are calling .ajax() on nothing. It's a syntactic error. Try jQuery.ajax(). Please spend at least 5 min on a question next time.

Comment: You want us to read the api for you? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: If it's an input type="button", you don't need to cancel the submit because that input doesn't submit the form.

Comment: ok got the type='button' part, I can understand it doesn't submit, my problem is the input won't display the $a,$b,$c based on <input> I have up there, where am I wrong on this part?

Comment: In the code you're showing us, you declare three jQuery objects, and then you make an ajax call that we can't see (and you have a syntax error, as @Ярослав Рахматуллин pointed out). We can't guess what do you do in *blah blah blah* part, and there are no more places where your code can do something with your input.

Comment: What do you want to do with $a, $b and $c? Have you tried to output their values to see if they're ok?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming .Bags has a submit action (which in your case it doesn't so the preventDefault is not needed:

```
$('.Bags').click(function(e){
    var $a = $(this).val();
    var $b = $(this).attr('id');
    var $c = $(this).attr('name');
    .ajax(blah blah blah); (this one I know - input/button is the issue)
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents default
    return false; // also prvents default (i like to add both but just the e.preventDefault is required :) )
});
```

Comment: but it would be an <input> not the <button>.  Will that above code gives the value I wanted out of the input I stated above?

Comment: Attach the function as the form's `submit` handler. Make sure that it returns `false` to suppress natural HTML form submission.